# SQL - show groups plus subgroups

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a StockLines table. See image below. How can I extract groups and group items at once from the server. The structure I want to extract from code is:
Site, 
Article,
List of StockLines

I do:

```
select top 20 Site, Article, SUM(Quantity) 
from StockLines 
group by Site, Article
```

that gives me the groups. Now foreach group I want to return 10 sub items. Should I create a new select foreach group to get its child items?

[image]

Comment: Sample data in a consumable format (not an image) and expected results will greatly help us, help you. An image doesn't help us at all, as we can't make any use of it. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing in your data is called "group" or "group item".  It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: `sql-server` will not run your query, select list contains `Customer, Product` which are missing in `group by`

Comment: @Serg you're totally right. As I stated the structure I want to extract from code is: Site, Article, List of StockLines. Updated the question

Comment: What are 10 items you want to return for a group?

Comment: @Serg I want to return sub items paginated aswell, only 10.

Answer (score 0):

This will return rows with least 10 `id`s (change it as needed) for every group of `Site, Article` along with the sum of all the rows in the group.

```
select * 
from(
    select *, sum(Quantity) over(partition by Site, Article) s
       -- change order by expression as needed 
      , row_number() over(partition by Site, Article order by Id) rn
    from StockLines
) t
where rn <= 10;
```

Comment: Corrected missing alias.